# DNS servers cant be changed UVERSE ATT ISP_Tried with beaver and Disco

Tags: networking, 18.04, dns, 19.04

Problem: Forced to go through AT&T DNS. Tried many workarounds and unable to use preferred DNS, such as openDNS, Google, Commodo, etc.

I have UVERSE ATT Internet provider.You can use static DNS on Ubuntu or Windows, and adapter settings will show it looking fine, for example:

```
local machine DHCP: 172.16.1.105
              SM:   255.255.0.0
              GW:   172.16.0.150
              DNS1: 1.1.1.1
              DNS2: 1.0.0.1
         IP 6 DNS:2606:4700:4700::1111
              DNS:2606:4700:4700::1001
```

trace route from Windows or Ubuntu, first 2 hops are AT&T.

Windows, Adapter: DHCP IP address and Static DNS settings.

Tracert out-doesn't not go to Clouflare-1.1.1.1 to resolve.

The only way I get around their DNS, is using a dual core VPN, with tor running under the VPN.

Ive tried resolv.conf in 16.04 and  NetworkPlan-->yaml in 19.04, with no success either.

@ vidarlo

```
dig google.com @8.8.8.8
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

With VPN connected: dig google.com @8.8.8.8
;; Query time: 1364 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Sat Apr 20 19:31:11 EDT 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 55
```

Comment: What are you asking about? Dual core vpn and tor? DNS? DNS settings? Remove *everything* that's unrelated to your question. To give you an answer, we have to understand what you try to achieve, and possible reasons for that failing.

Comment: DNS servers cant be changed UVERSE ATT ISP_Tried with beaver and Disco

Comment: Can you try `dig google.com @1.1.1.1` and `dig google.com @8.8.8.8` in a terminal? You probably have to install dig first with `sudo apt install dnsutils`. [Edit] your question to include the output of the dig commands.